# Nodes in wave functions outside of the classical turning point

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

When looking at the solutions of the classical harmonic oscillator for instance from wikipedia [image: From wikipedia]

one can observe that there are no nodes in the wavefunction outside the classical turning points. But I can't figure out a proof that this has to be the case. Especially considering an arbitrary Hamiltonian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This point is covered really well by Feynmann in Vol. 3 of the Lectures when he analyzes the finite potential square well. He shows how the curvature of the Schroedinger function changes from concave-out to concave-in when the energy goes negative. Same thing here.

Comment: Could you make that reference more precise?

Comment: Yeah, it's a little hard to find because it's not listed as the Potential Well in the Table of Contents. Section 16-6, "Quantized Energy Levels".